# Controlling the Z index of a Leaflet heatmap in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using the `leaflet` and `leaflet.extras` packages.
Trying to draw a **heatmap** on top of **polygons**, but can't get the polygons be "under" the heatmap.

Things that **don't** work:

- Changing the order of the calls for `addPolygons` and `addHeatmap`
- Setting a z-index using `addPolygons(options = list(zIndex = ...))`

**Minimal Example**

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons(lng = c(10, 20, 20, 10), lat = c(10, 10, 20, 20), fillOpacity = 0.75) %>%
  addHeatmap(lng = c(14, 15, 15, 16), lat = c(10, 10, 12, 10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflt.JS sets Z-indexes as named "panes". For example, the tilePane is 200, the overlayPane is 400 etc. see: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-pane

When you add your polygons, try setting the Heatmap layer to have a z-index of 450, or set the layer's leaflet option for a specific pane, for example, try:

```
addHeatmap(
    lng = c(14, 15, 15, 16), lat = c(10, 10, 12, 10), 
    options = pathOptions(pane = "overlayPane"))
```

Here is an example from the documentation for making your own custom pane:

```
# circles (zIndex: 420) are below the lines (zIndex: 430)
leaflet()%>%
addTiles() %>%
    # move the center to Snedecor Hall
    setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 14) %>%
    addMapPane("ames_lines", zIndex = 430) %>% # shown below ames_circles
    addMapPane("ames_circles", zIndex = 420) %>% # shown above ames_lines
    # points above polygons
    addCircles(
        data = random_data, ~lng, ~lat, radius = ~radius, popup = ~circleId,
        options = pathOptions(pane = "ames_circles")
    ) %>%
    # lines in'ames_lines'pane
    addPolylines(
        data = random_data, ~lng, ~lat, color = "#F00", weight = 20,
        options = pathOptions(pane = "ames_lines")    
    )
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet/leaflet.pdf pages 13-14.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! `addHeatmap` doesn't take the `options` argument but I was able to set a pane through `addPolygons(..., options = pathOptions(pane = ...))`.

Comment: Great. You could post the full code as an answer to your question. Others searching this question may find it helpful.

Comment: A full solution woul dbe greatly appreciated Yanir!

Comment: Yanir & @JMers could you please share the full solution? The above solution doesn't help.